# How to rollback transaction from service class?

Tags: spring, hibernate, orm, transactions, entitymanager

I am trying to rollback for some condition by throwing exception. But i can not find proper way to do this. Here is my service class

```
@Service
public class UserManager implements IUserManager {

    private final IBasicEM basicEM;

    public ApplicantInfoManager(IBasicEM basicEM) {
        this.basicEM = basicEM;
    }

    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public boolean purgeUser(Long id) throws Exception {
      //business logic
      basicEM.Update(entity)
      if(//condition) {
          throw New RollBackException("//message")
      }
      //business logic
    }
}
```

And here is my `BasicEM` class

```
@Component
@Transactional(value = "transactionManager", rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public class BasicEM {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "db1")
    private EntityManager em;

    public void update(Object target) {
        em.merge(target);
    }
}
```

So what i want is to call that `update` method, then if the condition is true undo the update.
My intention is that when i throw the exception, the transaction ends and does not commit the update. But i am wrong and the update is already done. Please help me to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want you will need to have a transaction already in the Service method. The default propagation type for `@Transactional(value = "transactionManager", rollbackFor = Exception.class)` is `Propagation.REQUIRED` which means that if your Service is already included in a transaction, the `basicEM.Update(entity)` will also be included in such transaction.

```java
@Service
public class UserManager implements IUserManager {

    private final IBasicEM basicEM;

    public ApplicantInfoManager(IBasicEM basicEM) {
        this.basicEM = basicEM;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(value = "transactionManager", 
       propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = RollBackException.class)
    public boolean purgeUser(Long id) throws Exception {
      //business logic
      basicEM.Update(entity)
      if(//condition) {
          throw New RollBackException("//message")
      }
      //business logic
    }
}
```

If `RollBackException` is a `RuntimeException` you don't need to explicitly configure that the transaction should rollback when it is thrown. If it is not, then you need to configure it as follows: `@Transactional(value = "transactionManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = RollBackException.class)`.

Comment: I dont have any `@Transactional` or any other annotation in my service class. Just the `@Service`. Should i add any annotation?

Comment: Yes, you need it. You can even apply it to a single method instead of applying it to the complete Service class.

Comment: Can you please provide the code?

Comment: Please add the Service code to your question so that I can provide the code with the needed changes.

Comment: Please check my updated code

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: I had to add `rollbackFor = RollBackException.class` in the annotation. Please update your answer then i can accept the answer